# How to avoid azure B2C code from taking windows credentials

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have integrated our application with Azure B2C active directory. So we used the required code to read the credentials in our application. But we observed that the code is reading the windows credentials by default so even if we manually enter some different credential still the application logs in as the windows credential user.

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
                MetadataAddress = String.Format(MSALSessionCache.AadInstance, MSALSessionCache.Tenant, MSALSessionCache.DefaultPolicy),

                // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
                ClientId = MSALSessionCache.ClientId,
                RedirectUri = MSALSessionCache.RedirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = MSALSessionCache.RedirectUri,

                // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                },

                // Specify the claim type that specifies the Name property.
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                },

                // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
                Scope = "openid profile offline_access " + MSALSessionCache.ReadTasksScope + " " + MSALSessionCache.WriteTasksScope
            }
        );
    }
```

We expect the code to take the credentials which is provided by the user instead of taking from windows logged in user. Is there any way to tweak the default functionality.

Comment: this seems weird. Could you please let us know more about client code, usually service side is not responsible for using integrated windows login. What is the client app here? Its client side code. If its a web app, could you please try in In-Private browser?

Comment: We have not written any client side code. The above code is written inside Startup.cs file. And its a MVC web application. Also we private mode is disabled in our machines so we cannot verify.

Comment: Could you please also share your MSALSessionCache confg file, or just the relavant configurations? I'll try to repro.